# Vue sort object data by selected property in table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I get from my api json object list like that:

```
"object123": {
  "selected": false, 
  "value": 0.54
},
```

In the frontend, I have table where I display this data with checkbox, how to sort this data by this select property? can you give me a small example?

I tried with

```
sortedData: function() {
  if(this.calculated) {
    return this.calculated.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.selected > b.selected
    })
  }
}
```

but then the table is empty.

Comment: can you provide an example of multiple objects in the variable `calculated`? Does it contain an object or an array?

Comment: Is `this.calculated` an array of objects?

Comment: Too long to paste here, https://pastebin.com/5XSAut8p
it is contained in this.calculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `sort()` function for an object.
In order to make your code work, you should convert `this.calculated` to an array.

You can use this code snippet to convert the object to an array.

```js
let calculated = {
  "object1": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 1
  },
  "object2": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 20
  },
  "object3": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 4
  },
  "object4": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 24
  },
  "object5": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 6
  },
  "object6": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 0.26
  },
  "object7": {
    "selected": true,
    "value": 1.52
  },
  "object8": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 0.54
  },
  "object9": {
    "selected": false,
    "value": 4.27
  }
}

let calculatedArray = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(calculated)) {
  calculatedArray.push({
    id: key,
    ...value
  })
}

sortedData = function() {
  if(calculatedArray) {
    return calculatedArray.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.selected - a.selected
    })
  } else {
    return []
  }
}

console.log(sortedData())
console.log(calculatedArray)
```

Comment: Then when i change selected to true, should be at the first position of array but is in the same order

Comment: Thanks!! works fine. I never would have thought of it.